# Not getting the result I expected from this calculation

Tags: javascript

I'm using a form to help determine the strength for an action in a game I'm making a plugin for. The player fills in some form fields and selects 1 value from a drop down and then clicks calculate. The result if I use an actual calculator is what I expected but, the result from my javascript function is not. I've been wrestling with it for a while but, can't seem to work out why it's failing to calculate correctly. Below is the function:

```
function wgtcalc() {
  document.wgtcalc.strDSAtk.value = 
    (document.wgtcalc.strBaseSpeed.value * document.wgtcalc.strAltitude1.value) + 
    (document.wgtcalc.strBaseSpeed.value * document.wgtcalc.strAltitude2.value) + 
    (document.wgtcalc.strDistance.value / document.wgtcalc.strFullSwing.value);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs for each value and the expected output?

Comment: With the values being:
strBaseSpeed = 10.75
strAltitude1 = 12
strAltitude2 = 0
strDistance = 36
strFullSwing = 60

I would expect the result to be .815 which I would then multiply by 100 to get a percentage value to display to the player. What I'm getting instead is 13?

Comment: Maybe you implemented the formula incorrectly, how should we know?

Comment: you're trying to calculat strings, try parseInt or parseFloat befor calculating

Comment: We need more information. What is the formula? What are the input values and the output you expect? Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: @pc-shooter: won't really make a difference since the operators convert to numbers first.

Comment: it is impossible to say what is wrong with what you have specified.  My guess is that you have parenthesis matched differently than you expect.  Currently you have (baseSpeed*altitude1) + (baseSpeed*altitude2) + (distance/fullSwing)...

Comment: So if I'm understanding you it should be (10.75 * 12) + (10.75 * 0) + (36 / 60) which would be 129.6, I don't really understand how you expect it to be .815.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function wgtcalc() {
  document.wgtcalc.strDSAtk.value = 
    ( Number(document.wgtcalc.strBaseSpeed.value) *  
      Number (document.wgtcalc.strAltitude1.value)) + 
    ( Number (document.wgtcalc.strBaseSpeed.value) *  
      Number (document.wgtcalc.strAltitude2.value)) + 
    ( Number (document.wgtcalc.strDistance.value) /  
      Number (document.wgtcalc.strFullSwing.value) );
}
```

As pc-shooter pointed out you're doing a calculation on strings.

Comment: And as I pointed out, the * and / operators convert their operands to numbers first. While it's good to explicitly convert the values, it won't make a difference in this case.

Comment: I tried setting up a Fiddle but, was unable to get it to recognize my javascript function. The basic "formula" I'm trying to work out is: (distance + (green speed * altitude)) / full swing

Comment: @shc: change `onload` to `no wrap` in the jsfiddle configuration (top left) and it will "work".

Comment: I guess I'm just not understanding how the actual math mechanics are working. If I set the values of my variables correctly, then how is the "math" executed? In something like Algebra you would do the math in brackets first and then take the results and use them in the rest of the problem. IE x=6 so (x+5) x 4 = 44 not 26 which would be x + 5 x 4.

My not being able to get a working jsfiddle aside, what are the order of transactions in the math of a javascript? 

Thanks everyone!

Comment: @shc: the order is exactly how you expect it. However, your code does not calculate `(distance + (green speed * altitude)) / full swing`, it computes something like `(green speed * altitude1) + (green speed * altitude2) + (distance / full swing)`, which may or may not be the same.